# Should I fix whole house filter just after the pump?

Tags: pump, filter, water-filtration

I have a 1 HP Monobloc pump lifting water from an underground reservoir to two overhead tanks (2x 1000 ltr) which are at a height of 25-28 feet. The supply from the tank splits in 2 parts for the first and the second floor. For the first floor I need a pressure pump for the toilet line.

The water being very dirty and muddy I am planning to use three stage big blue filter (10" x 4.5" each) with 1" ports and a pre-filter (sediment strainer) on the pump inlet.

I want to ask if I can fix the 3 stage filter on the outlet of the pump as otherwise there is no way to clean the water for both lines. The line- 2 provides no option or position to fix such filters. If needed I can change the pump with a higher capacity. Please advise me the right position.
[image: Rough drawing of water line]

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the filter on the pump outlet. If you put the filter on the inlet it may cause pump cavitation but on the output side the pressure will push the water through with no problem.

Remember that filters on drinking water systems need to be replaced regularly to prevent things from growing. Many times UV systems are added to reduce risk of growth in filter systems. Pre-filters on a pump can be good and bad. If the filter gets plugged it will limit the flow to the pump and shorten the life. I like screen filters to prevent small grit from wearing the pump, but  these may need to be cleaned quite often depending on the size of the filter and amount of water pumped.

Comment: Thanks ! I am planning to use a 'Rusco' sediment trapper on the inlet within view and which can be cleaned easily.

Comment: I agree but some filters need the pressure tank between the pump so the filter beds are not damaged by the pulsating pressure from the pump. I don't see a pressure tank so that should be checked to make sure the filter media won't fail.

Answer (score 1):

How muddy is muddy?  If you can see mud in the water, then the 10-inch big-blue filters will clog up quickly.  You may want to consider the course spin-down sediment filter before the inlet of the pump and then another one with a finer mesh (say 400 mesh / 37 micron) before the big blues.

For the pump, lookup the maximum head for the pump.  You are lifting it 27 feet so far and the filters will add some additional head due to the filter resistance.  Probably count on an additional 10 to 20 feet head for the entire set of filters.

I have a similar system to yours fed with rainwater.  The rainwater goes through a course filter before going into the surge tank (same as your storage tank), then a submersible pump followed by three 10" big-blue filters (10 micron, 1 micron, KDF), a UV filter, and then into storage the 50,000L overhead storage tank.  The water gravity feeds to a booster pump which then runs the water through an ultrafiltration filter (0.01 micron) and UV again.  The ultrafiltration filter bypass water feeds the toilets and the filtered water is drinkable and goes to the house.